# TKinter background resizer + buttons/labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to setup tkinter gui screen with wallpaper on the background when the bg image fit the resize of the screen, i have took code from here..but the problem is when i'm trying to put buttons on it or another labels, the wallpaper still stay on the top and i can't see them.

Here the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry("800x600")

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.configure(background="black")
        self.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.image = Image.open("bg.jpg")
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()
        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.grid(row =0, column =0,sticky="nsew")
        self.background.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.background.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.master = master
        self.master.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

        # create a button
        self.button= Button(root, text="EXIT", width=4).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    def _resize_image(self,event):
        new_width = self.master.winfo_width()
        new_height = self.master.winfo_height()

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)

e = Example(root)
e.grid(row =0, column =0,sticky="nsew")
e.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
e.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should use `place()` on the background image.  Also where is the button to be added? `root` or `self`?

Comment: Thanks for helping! i need add the buttons above the image, not really change where..how you do it with place() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `place()` to put the background image so that it does not interfere other widgets in the same parent.

Below is a simplified example based on your code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.configure(background="black")

        self.image = Image.open("bg.jpg")

        # label for the background image
        self.background = Label(self)
        self.background.place(x=0, y=0)

        self.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

        # create a button
        self.button = Button(self, text="EXIT", width=4)
        self.button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=50, pady=50)

    def _resize_image(self,event):
        if event.widget is self:
            # resize background image to fit the frame size
            image = self.image.resize((event.width, event.height))
            self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            self.background.configure(image=self.background_image)

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry("800x600")

e = Example(root)
e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for help! you resolve my problem, but now if i want to add more buttons when each one open another window with another options, how i can do it?

Comment: You can assign a callback via `command` option of `Button`, then you can do whatever you want inside the callback.  If you have problem on that, better create another question.